# C++, how do i solve a keyword "delete" error?

Tags: visual-c++

Sorry for my English.

```
struct Menu{
   int fno;
   string fname;
   int price;
};

struct Order {
   int table; 
   int fcnt; 
   Menu *foods;
   int *qty;   
   int ord_price;  
   bool checked = false;
```

};

```
void del_order(Order *ord[], int &pos) {
   int table, loc;
   cout << "* table(1-10) : "; cin >> table;
   for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
      if (ord[i]->table == table) {
         if ((ord[i]->checked)) {
             cout << "cannot delete.\n";
             return;
         }
         loc = i;
         delete ord[i]->foods;  <---- this errors!!.
         delete ord[i]->qty;
      }
   }
   delete ord[loc];
   pos--;
   for (int i = loc; i < pos; i++)
       ord[i] = ord[i + 1];
}
```

**delete ord[i]->foods;**  I think this caused a error msg .
The content of the error is as shown in the attached img.
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown sufficient code, but almost certainly `Order::foods` is a pointer acquired via *array-new* (`operator new[]`), or it was never allocated but is non-NULL (dangling / uninitialized).

You must always match your new / delete calls correctly:

- if you allocated with `new`, then release with `delete`: *e.g.*

  ```
  Menu *m = new Menu;
  delete m;
  ```
- if you allocated with `new[]`, then release with `delete[]`: *e.g.*

  ```
  Menu *m = new Menu[10];
  delete[] m;
  ```